# Strange limitation on single TCP/UDP connection with bandwidth limitation

Tags: tcp, tunnel, udp

I have a weird behaviour with connections from my house in Israel to my VPS or dedicated server in the EU.

A single connection TCP/UDP is somehow limited to around 400kbps for some reason. When using lftp with multiple connections, I can use my 1Gbps connection almost with full speed.

If I open up a tunnel—for example with Wireguard/OpenVPN or even use a proxy like Shadowsocks—the limit is still 400kbps with a single connection but an lftp inside of the tunnel will go up to 1Gbps again.

However I cannot use lftp to, for example, stream content through the tunnel, and with 400kbps there is nonstop buffering.

I have tried different routers with no luck.

Both ends run Linux (I tried Windows as well, but same issue).

Do any of you know where there might be an issue with this?

Comment: (1) Are you on a Dell computer with the SmartByte application installed? (2) Is this happening on other networks than your place? (3) Try the commands at the end of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1641962/8672). (4) Is this happening when booting in Safe Mode with Network? (Add to your answering comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc thanks for your reply. I am using Arch Linux. I have tried different PCs, Modems and Phones (LAN or WLAN). I even tried it at a different house with the same ISP. Different ISP has no issue.

Comment: Since the connection specific limit happens also when using a VPN it cannot be the ISP, since it cannot distinguish connections inside the VPN. Thus it is either on your end or on the VPS end. It could be a setting in your FTP server if limited to FTP. It could be a setting in your VPS iptables if it also covers non-FTP connections. Too much unknown about the server and how you tested apart from using lftp.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich It must be something ISP related, as a different ISP with same hardware has no issues. Even if I use my cellulars Internet its faster....

Comment: @Dennis: If both the VPN and the FTP are between your client and the VPS then please make sure that the FTP actually goes through the VPN. If the tunnel instead ends somewhere else the speedup might be due to a faster route. Sometimes ISP choose a cheaper route and not the more expensive faster route and building a tunnel to some external host with VPN can work around this.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I use SFTP through the VPN tunnel. VPN only on 10.8.0.0/24 all Services on VPS only listening on 10.8.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

If this problem only happens with a single ISP, then it seems like
the problem is with this ISP capping single-connection speeds.

Phone their Support and ask for a change; perhaps you need to move to
different (costlier) plan.

If nothing helps, use another ISP.